Can self-leveling concrete go over a rough 1 inch mud-set mortar tile base?
Single story Florida home, concrete slab.
Half the kitchen floor was linoleum, other half was an uneven spanish tile recessed into slab to be even with the linoleum side. We want to install new flooring over all.
The tile has been removed from the top of mortar base leaving a 1 inch deep 'mud-set' mortar base on the recessed half of slab.
In a few places the mud-base is chipped down through to the slab.
Can leveling concrete be used over the remaining rough mortar base for the new floor install or must the mortar base be removed?
If the mud base is still well adhered it would save the effort of breaking out the mud-set tile base and new concrete replacing it.
Thanks.

yes, but leveling concrete is the most expensive kind. It might pay to fill some of the larger divots with mortar first.
